# Azure route table not showing effective routes

Tags: azure-virtual-network

I have this Vnet and subnet and I created a route table and associated it to the subnet. However, under Effective routes, it is empty... I also have a VNet Gateway and it has a VPN to on-prem and the gateway is learning BGP routes but they are not listed here. I do have a NIC associated in the subnet as well. The NIC's menu shows all the routes. Why is that? Here is the screenshot of it. The route table is empty here

[image]

The route table is associated to this subnet
[image]

Here is the NIC in the subnet and it shows all the routes
[image]
[image]

Thanks!
Difan

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the same in my environment. Its working fine this issue may cause of required [permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-network-interface#permissions) and connection fails.

***Go to Azure portal -> Your VM -> setting -> click networking -> select your network interface -> click effective routes***

[image]

Named of effective routes as shown below:

[image]

Otherwise try to fix it via PowerShell

To Get the effective route table on a network interface

```
 Get-AzEffectiveRouteTable -NetworkInterfaceName "MyNetworkInterface" -ResourceGroupName "MyResourceGroup
```

To  gets the effective routes for a network interface

```
Get-AzEffectiveRouteTable `
  -NetworkInterfaceName myVMNic1 `
  -ResourceGroupName myResourceGroup `
  | Format-Table
```

For your Reference :

[az network nic | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/nic?view=azure-cli-latest#az-network-nic-show-effective-route-table)

Comment: Sorry for not being clear... It is that the "route table" doesn't show the effective routes while the "nic" shows them... Could you take a look at my screenshot and let me know what you think? Anyway, thank you for your response!

Comment: kindly refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/manage-route-table) to View effective routes